# AWS Lambda Query Athena and chose name of result file

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-athena

I am doing a Python script that runs a query on AWS Athena in AWS Lambda. The result are sent to my s3 bucket as csv and metadata files.
Here is the script :

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('athena')

    QueryResponse = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString = "SELECT id from campaign;",
        QueryExecutionContext = {
            'Database' : 'raw'
        },
        ResultConfiguration = {
            'OutputLocation' : 's3://my-bucket-name'
        }
    )


    #Oberserve results : 
    queryId = QueryResponse['QueryExecutionId']
    time.sleep(10)

    results = client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId = queryId)
    for row in results['ResultSet']['Rows']:
        print(row)
```

The code works fine, but I would like to choose the name of the resulting csv file in s3. Any ideas on how I could do that ?

Thank's for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to select the name output file, the name is formed as `<QueryExecutionId>.csv`. You can then rename the output file using the s3 api.

Comment: Ok thank's. But if I can't choose it's name, is there a way to get it's name (it might means get the name of the last CSV file uploaded in the s3 bucket) ?My objective is to proceed automatic analysis on this file and then delete it. So I might have to get it's name and store it as a string to do so.

Comment: yes, the name is given by the query execution id which you are storing as `queryId`, it would be `{queryId}.csv`

Comment: Well yes, I just tryied and it works perfectly. Thank you for that explanation, I didn't know where that "random" name was coming from. Thanks for helping